# How can we use two SWRevealViewController in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, swrevealviewcontroller

My requirement is I have to implement two SWRevelViewController. I have to show two right view for a single view controller. I mean I have to use RevealView for two View controllers,But it is showing error if I am doing through storyboard.

Can I do by programmatically? Or any alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Going through your comment "I have a View controller ok, I have to show left view reveal. I have one more view controller and for that i want to show right reveal. So for two different view controllers how can i get it"

You can Add Two reveal controller's home but with Different Storyboard Ids

[image]

As screenshot provided you can set the class name for that second view controller on which you are willing to have reveal with right menu, with different storyboard id.

Now we have to set rear and front controllers for swreveal controller
Steps to set Swreveaal front and real view controller

1. Add two View controllers for rear and front view
2. Now drag seques  and set class to the segue SWRevealViewControllerSegueSetController.
3. now as in screen shot below set "sw_rear" for rear view controller and set "sw_front" for front view controller.

[image]

[image]

for setting right view controller

[image]

1. Now add right button on your target controller from where right menu is needed

You can invoke right menu as

```
   if self.revealViewController() != nil {

        toggleMenuBtn.addTarget( self.revealViewController(), action:#selector(SWRevealViewController.rightRevealToggle(_:)) , forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())

    }
```

Comment: OK Thanks
Let me try.

Comment: Sure, or there is another solution, you can change rear controller for particular vc, on which you can invoke that rear menu with custom method of method.

Comment: Actually i got confused

Comment: feel free to ask!

Comment: Actually I have a view controller and for that already one sw_rear is there.
Now I have one more view controller in that dropDown button is there , So when i click on dropdown button right side sw_right should open and if I click on a cell then again one more sw_right view should open.
What should i do?

Comment: You are right.
But I am saying once sw_right will open then in sw_right view i will click on a cell then again one sw_right view should open.
Anyone your answer gave me some solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using storyboard too. You can do it by making custom segue with the front and back VC. And Assign custom segue on selection of backTableVC row.

This link will helps you:
 http://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/

Comment: I know this front and back vc.
But thing is it's totally different.
I mean for a View controller front and rear is there and for one more view controller I have to do same

Comment: Your BackVC will be rear.. All other controllers will be front. And Connect each cell of backVC with other front controllers through custom segue